# How come my model is not updating?

Tags: ios, oop, swift, model-view-controller, segue

First, I have a struct. This is my model

```
struct DiscoverySettings {
    var alert:Bool
    var distance:Int
    var minAge: Int
    var maxAge: Int
    private init(){
        alert = true
        distance = 50
        minAge = 18
        maxAge = 100
    }
}

extension UIViewController{
    var contentViewController: UIViewController{
        if let navcon = self as? UINavigationController{
            return navcon.visibleViewController
        }else{
            return self
        }
    }
}

// View Controller 1
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
    let discovery_model = DiscoverySettings()
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == Constants.EditDiscoverSegue {
            if let dseg = segue.destinationViewController.contentViewController as? DiscoverySettingsViewController {
                dseg.dsettings = discovery_model
            }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func unwindToSettings(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
        println(discovery_model.minAge)
        println(discovery_model.maxAge)
    }
...

//View Controller 2
class DiscoverySettingsViewController: UIViewController  {

    var dsettings: DiscoverySettings? {
        didSet{
            render()
        }
    }

    func rangeSliderValueChanged(rangeSlider: RangeSlider) {
        println("Range slider value changed: (\(Int(rangeSlider.lowerValue)) , \(Int(rangeSlider.upperValue)))")
        var low = Int(rangeSlider.lowerValue)
        var high = Int(rangeSlider.upperValue)
        dsettings?.minAge = low //this does not set the original model!
        dsettings?.maxAge = high //this does not set the original model!
    }
...
```

When I drag my slider and then click "Save" to unwind to the origin segue, I print out the max age and min age. However, they print 18 and 100. They don't print the value that I changed in my slider. (However, the print statements all work, so the slider is working fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the funny difference between structs and classes. Structs are passed by value -- a whole copy is created at each assignment.

Classes on the other hand are passed by reference -- no copy made on assignments.

In your case the two troubling assignments worked alright, but only locally and never impacted your controller.

Use `class` for `DiscoverySettings` and see the difference.

Comment: Note: if you need to use structs, however, you'll have to pass the new values through a callback closure so that the controller can assign (therefore copy) the edited model into its own copy.

Comment: I switched it to "class" but it still displays the initial value.  I also switched "let" to "var" when creating the model.

Comment: If you breakpoint at the two assignments, is `dsettings` nil?

Comment: I solved the problem. Turns out my identifier wasn't even set.